# Insert into BULK COLLECT by running a dynamic query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

I want to insert into table from running a dynamic query. How can I achieve it. below is what I am trying.

```
VARIABLE a REFCURSOR;

DECLARE
 PROCEDURE Pr_Get_VARIANCE_REPORT (p_billing_system_id   IN  NUMBER ,
                                        p_Sorting IN Varchar2,
                                    po_Cur_Out    OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR)
  IS
       v_query1 varchar2(3000);


v_query1 := 'Select Plan_No, Plan_name from TB_BISBILL 
             where Billing_System_ID = p_billing_system_id ORDER BY '
             || p_Sorting ;

SELECT PLAN_NO, Plan_name 
 bulk collect into  l_invoices 
from (I need to insert by executing the v_query1).
```

How can I do this.

here since the sorting is provided by user so < i have to order by whatever column name provided by user.

Comment: Thanks Gurwinder Singh

Comment: As an aside, if you're going to do this, you should run the sort parameter through `DBMS_ASSERT.SIMPLE_SQL_NAME` as a safety precaution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
execute immediate v_query1 bulk collect into l_invoices;
```